# Refresh Data of Windows Phone Panorama Item

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application using the Panorama Page. 
I have around 5-6 Panorama items in my page which the user can scroll.

Currently i am binding the data of those pages when the Panorama page is loaded. Some of my Panorama items fetch data from the web service. For those pages,  i want to fetch data only when the user scrolls to that item .

How can i achieve that ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a handler for your Panorama's [SelectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectionchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) event and inspect the Panorama's [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selectedindex%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.panorama.selecteditem%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) properties to determine if the desired PanoramaItem is selected.

**XAML**

```
<phone:Panorama x:Name="myPanorama" Title="my application" SelectionChanged="Panorama_SelectionChanged">

    <!--Panorama item one-->
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item1">
        <Grid/>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>

    <!--Panorama item two-->
    <phone:PanoramaItem Header="item2">
        <Grid/>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
</phone:Panorama>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myPanorama.SelectedIndex == 2)
    {
        // Take on-demand actions
    }
}
```